# Redshift Aginity Workbench - ERROR: 42703: column "XXX" does not exist in table_y

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

I've been using MySQL Workbench for a while and now I need to work on Aginity - I'm trying to run a simple script:

```
select min(date)
from table_y 
where column_header = "XXX"
```

Yet I get this error:

`ERROR: 42703: column "XXX" does not exist in table_y`

Does the Where command works differently in Aginity than in MySQL Workbench? How do I solve for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So "=" and "IN" are different sql commands.

I think the problem with your original query is that you are using double quotes instead of single.

Try this:

```
select min(date)
from table_y 
where column_header = 'XXX'
```

Comment: It worked! I guess the difference between Aginity and MySQL Workbench is the use of 'xx' vs "xx"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

It seems that in Aginity the syntax of the command Where is different that in MySQL Workbench.

MySQL Workbench:

```
Select (*)
From table_a
Where column_a = 2015
```

Aginity

```
Select (*)
From table_a
Where column_a in (2015)
```